# PHP Regular expression stopped working although unchanged

Tags: php, regex

```
//START GET DATES
$regexp = '/[0-9]{2,4}[-\/ ]{1}([A-Za-z]{3}|[0-9]{2})[-\/ ]{1}[0-9]{2,4}/i';

preg_match_all($regexp, $output, $dates);

//Dec 05, 1995 + December 5, 1995
$regexp = '/\b[[A-Za-z]{3,9}\b[ 0-9\,]{2,5}[0-9]{4}/i';
preg_match_all($regexp, $output, $dates);

//09 Aug 2012
$regexp = '/[0-9]{2}[ ]{1}[A-Za-z]{3}[ ]{1}[0-9]{4}/i';
preg_match_all($regexp, $output, $dates);
print_r($dates);
```

The above is my regular expression to extract dates of different formats from a clump of text..

The expression was working perfectly, and as far as I can remember absolutely nothing has been changed..

Can anyone tell me if anything is wrong with the expressions, and if not what else could have caused this sudden break?

Cheers

Comment: What sudden break? Why do you think that something is wrong? _Something_ must have changed. What happens when you run them?

Comment: Can you give us a sample input?

Comment: Also, http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php might be useful

Comment: @Joey: This is not about parsing dates, this is about finding dates in a larger body of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without some more information it's hard to give a precise answer, but a few things come to mind:

- These are some sloppy regexes.

  - `[A-Za-z]` and then the case-insensitive option.
  - `[[A-Za-z]`.
  - `{1}` (repeatedly).
  - Needless escapes, and more. I wouldn't be surprised if there were errors in them, too.
- You're applying the regexes in sequence. I don't know PHP, but it looks like the results of the previous matches are overwritten by the next `preg_match_all`. Perhaps you do have results, but they are overwritten by the next regex which happens not to have any matches?

So let's try to find a better regex for you, a single one. How about this:

```
preg_match_all(
    '%\b                  # Start at a word boundary
    (?:                   # Match the following:
     (?:                  # either
      \d+\b               # a number,
      (?:\.|st|nd|rd|th)* # followed by a dot, st, nd, rd, or th (optional)
      |                   # or a month name
      (?:(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*)\b
     )
     [\s.,/-]*            # followed by a date separator, comma or whitespace (opt.)
    ){3}                  # Do this three times
    (?<!\s)               # Don\'t match trailing whitespace
    %ix', 
    $output, $dates, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$dates = $dates[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - having printed each array after, it does seem to be the case that each regex is overwriting those prior..

I am trying to extract dates in all formats.. hence i thought it easier to do multiple expressions. Furthermore i am new to regex, and this was the simplest approach..

2000-11-29
09-Aug-2000
Dec 05, 1995
December 05, 1995
2013-2-9

etc etc

Could you elaborate as to why the problems you have mentioned above are problems?

Many Thanks

Comment: The problems above are not problems per se, they are just telltale signs for a regex newbie, leading me to the assumption that they also might have errors. `{1}` is a no-op, `[[A-Za-z]` includes the `[` in the character class, etc. "All formats" is going to be difficult. I did write one that covered quite a lot of formats; I hope I can find it. Must be here on SO somewhere...

Comment: OK, I've found it and modified it to work in PHP. It works on all the date formats you have listed and many others. It will also match nonsense (88/88/88 etc. or Aug/August/Augias), so you'll have to parse the results to validate them.

Comment: Tim, Thanks so much - works perfectly (from initial testing), and a very comprehensive answer... much appreciated.

You are correct to say that I'm a regex newb :) I am looking into/researching further explanation of the regex you provided.. I will comment if I have any problems - hopefully that is OK.

Many Thanks

Comment: Tim. I am curious as to your insight on a small problem I am having. 
The regex works perfectly, however as you mentioned it extracts phone numbers too.

If I extract an array of: '123-456.123','23-12-2009', and '30-09-2006' and then explode each using the - seperator, the phone number throws up error namely undefined indexes.

Is there any resolution to this given the number/variety if date formats i need to extract? Thx

Comment: @ThomasClowes: I think the best way would be to try and parse whatever the regex extracts, and if this error is thrown, catch it and consider the string it was working on as "not a date" - and just ignore it. I wouldn't try and modify the regex to match these cases - there'll always be mismatches that you'll have to weed out afterwards when applying a regex to that kind of inconsistent real-world data that.

Comment: Many Thanks Tim. My only concern is that although on production noone sees these 'notices' It is not perfect code which is my ideal. I can catch the errors and 'deal' with them per se but it doesn't seem like the final solution :)

Comment: @ThomasClowes: I see what you mean, but the world is like that. Read Jon Skeet's [OMG Ponies!!! Aka Humanity: Epic Fail](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx).